# Purpose of xcopy over robocopy

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, robocopy, xcopy

From what I've found online, `robocopy` seems to be `xcopy` with more features; are there any scenarios where someone would want to use `xcopy` over `robocopy`?

Comment: I dont know anything about robocopy but xcopy was included as part of the OS going back an extremely long time - so there are probably a number if scripts that expect it.

Comment: @davidgo are you saying that some (older?) scripts might not be using xcopy because they were written a long time ago

Comment: no, he means the opposite. xcopy has been in use for at least 35 years, included in every MS OS ever released (goes back to DOS 3.2 in 1986), whereas robocopy has only been included in the OS by default since 2006 or so (vista/server 2k8). if I was in a dos environment, or in windows 9x/nt/me/2k/xp I'd use xcopy.

Comment: [`robocopy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) is more versatile, especially with ACLs _(allows exactly mirroring a directory's/file's ACLs upon copying via `/sec`, even if the user doesn't have access privs to the files)_, exclusions, and monitoring _(it can monitor a file/directory for changes and copy/move files/directories based upon an arbitrary change)_, as well as saving command parameters as a `RoboCopy` job [`.rcj`] for calling upon next time. Simply put, it's better than `xcopy` in almost every way.

Comment: I've always thought that `robocopy` was a response to `rsync` more than anything else. windows admins needed a tool with advanced features to make up for missing features in the command shell that were common in contemporary linux shells, and was reliable over the network. xcopy can only work over the network if drives have been previously mapped.

Comment: @FrankThomas You are right about interpreting my meaning.   According to https://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm xcopy was released for MSDos 3.3 - which Concords with my memory of it not being in MSDos version 2.   (I remember not knowing anything, stumbling across the output of dir and typing everything I saw... if only the internet was available to kids back then)

Comment: @FrankThomas Oh my bad I got my words mixed up, I meant to type robocopy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121046/difference-between-xcopy-and-robocopy FTW